# Django Models LookUp Through Field

Tags: python, django

I have models defined as follows:

```
class Perfcrew(models.Model):
    perfcrewid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    performanceid = models.ForeignKey('Performance', db_column='performanceid', blank=True, null=True)
    crewid = models.ForeignKey(Crew, db_column='crewid', blank=True, null=True)
    responsiblities = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='responsiblities',blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Crew on Performance. Name: {0}, Responsibility: {1}'.format(self.crewid, self.responsiblities)
        # self.productionid, self.stageid, self.starttime, self.info,self.actors, self.crews)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'perfcrew'


class Performance(models.Model):
    performanceid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    info = models.TextField(blank=True)
    stageid = models.ForeignKey('Stage', db_column='stageid', blank=True, null=True)
    starttime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    productionid = models.ForeignKey('Production', db_column='productionid', blank=True, null=True)
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, through='Perfactor', through_fields=( 'performanceid', 'actorid'))
    crews = models.ManyToManyField(Crew, through='Perfcrew', through_fields=('performanceid', 'crewid'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Production: {0}, Stage: {1}, Start Time: {2}, Info: {3}, Actor: {4}, Crew: {5}'.format(
        self.productionid, self.stageid, self.starttime, self.info,self.actors.filter(pk=3) ,self.crews.all())
        # self.productionid, self.stageid, self.starttime, self.info,self.actors, self.crews)
    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'performance'

class Crew(models.Model):
    crewid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Crew: {0}, Bio:{1}".format(self.name, self.bio)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'crew'
```

A performance has many crew, and the crew can be on many performances. I am trying to get a list of crew for each performance:

```
Performance.crews.all()
```

but it always blank. Is there something I am doing wrong? How should I be referencing the crew objects related to performance? I have confirmed from the data in the database that there are items in there conforming to this relation ship ie there are crews, and related perfcrew entries.

I am querying like this:

```
> perf = Performance.objects.all()[0]
> perf.crews.all()
> []
```

The PerfCrew is properly populated.

Comment: Could you paste your queries? Did you use exact `Performance.crews.all()`? That is wrong. `Performance` is the model class, you need to query with a instance/record of the model, e.g. `perf1 = Performance.objects.all()[0]; perf1.crews.all()`

Comment: Can you post the code where you are querying?

Comment: @ZZY ... I have added the querying code.

Comment: @ZZY I tried your suggestion, it doesn't work. I get the error: 'QuerySet has no attribute crews'

Comment: @RaymondMachira no, you would *not* get that error if you followed ZZY's code correctly. Try it again, copying and pasting the code exactly.

Comment: `Performance.objects.all()[0:1]` caused 'QuerySet has no attribute crews'. `[0:1]` gives a list of objects/instances/records, while `crews` should apply to a single object. So use `[0]` or `[0:1].get()` or `for perf in Performance.objects.filter(...): perf.crews....`instead. Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @ZZY, I have updated, and now it's blank- like the original problem description. What else am I doing wrong? Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: How are you populating the `crews` field? This doesn't look like it should raise any issues... Are you performing `perf.crews.add(crew)`?

Comment: One possibility is the first Performance record in your DB doesn't have any related crews. What's the output of `Perfcrew.objects.all()`? If there are some records in perfcrew table, what's output of `Perfcrew.objects.all()[0].performanceid.crews.all()`?